# XPATH evaluation against child node

Tags: java

I have xml as follows,

```
<students>
<Student><age>23</age><id>2000</id><name>PP2000</name></Student>
<Student><age>23</age><id>1000</id><name>PP1000</name></Student>
</students>
```

I have 2 xpaths Template XPATH = `students/Student` will be the template nodes, but I cannot hard code this xpath, because it will change for other XMLs, and XML is pretty dynamic, can expand (but with the same base XPATHs) So if I evaluate one more XPATH using the template node, I'm using the following code,

```
XPath xpathResource = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Document xmlDocument = //creating document;
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xpathResource.compile("//students/Student").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nodeList.getLength(); nodeIndex++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(nodeIndex);
        String xpathID = "//students/Student/id";
        String xpathName = "//students/Student/name";
        NodeList childID = (NodeList)xpathResource.compile(xpathID).evaluate(currentNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList childName = (NodeList)xpathResource.compile(xpathName).evaluate(currentNode, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        System.out.println("node ID " +childID.item(0).getTextContent());
        System.out.println("node Name " +childName.item(0).getTextContent());
    }
```

Now the problem is, this for loop will execute for 2 times, but both time I'm getting `2000 , PP2000` as ID value. Is there any way to iterate to the child node with generic XPATH against a node. I cannot go generic XPATH against the whole XMLDocument, I have some validation to do. I want to use XML nodelist as result set rows, so that I can validate the XML value and do my stuff.

Comment: Change this System.out.println("node " +child.item(0).getTextContent()); to System.out.println("node " +child.item(nodeIndex).getTextContent());

Comment: Also there is no need to iterate the first NodeList. Just remove the for cycle and leave the last two lines in the for cycle. Then iterate the child NodeList to obtain all studentIds.

Comment: @pringi I cannot go with nodeIndex, if the 2nd `Student` doesn't have `name` node, I may end up with index exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    XPath xpathResource = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    Document xmlDocument = //creating document;
    NodeList nodeList = (NodeList)xpathResource.compile("//students/Student/id").evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);

for (int nodeIndex = 0; nodeIndex < nodeList.getLength(); nodeIndex++) {
        Node currentNode = nodeList.item(nodeIndex);

        System.out.println("node " +currentNode.getTextContent());
    }
```

Comment: I need ID and Name also. Like a recordset, if it is single node, I can do it well, it depends on multiple nodes, that's why I'm at SO now.. :)

Comment: Try this: JXPathContext.newContext(currentNode).getValue("//students/Student/id");  To obtain name is similar